# How can I get two clickbale images side by side using just plane HTML

Tags: html

I have no basic clue about html and and right now am kinda stuck, I need two images side by side around the bottom half part of a email template, thing is no matter what I do I can't get the image to be side by side. there is already a hero image on the email template I am not sure if that's what causing the error. Can you please help me with this or give me some learning metrials so that I can figure this out.

Can you please help me with this or give me some learning metrials so that I can figure this out.

PS: Please don't mind the rickroll video, I added it to replace the link

The below code is how the banner hero image is setup

```
<tr>
              <td class="hero" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" align="center" valign="top">
                <a title="placeholdertext" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                  <img class="fr-dib" style="width: 620px; max-width: 560px; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; padding: 0px; outline: currentcolor none medium; text-decoration: none;" title="rick roll" src="test_mail_f.jpg" alt="rick roll" width="560" height="349" border="0" />
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<table>`, it should be compatible with Outlook email client as well. For more on HTML email see this [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/04/complete-guide-html-email-templates-tools/).

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placem.at/places?w=160&h=90&random=1&txt=1&txtclr=fc0">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placem.at/places?w=160&h=90&random=1&txt=2&txtclr=fc0">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this, this is taking over the whole mailer, thank you though

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by several ways. The easiest is use another table in td with two columns, like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="hero" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" align="center" valign="top">
    <a title="placeholdertext" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
       <img class="fr-dib" style="width: 620px; max-width: 560px; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; padding: 0px; outline: currentcolor none medium; text-decoration: none;" title="rick roll" src="test_mail_f.jpg" alt="rick roll" width="560" height="349" border="0" />
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="#">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Don't forget to let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: I tried this, but this is taking over the whole mailer, thank you though, I think I just need to add custom height and width to solve this. can you please help me with that as well?

Comment: Really sorry for late reply. I guess your problem is resolved by now. If not, try this in CSS:   img{max-width:100%}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `display: flex;` property, which automatically makes the flow of the content inside a container to a row.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <img src="example.com" />
    <img src="example.com" />
</div>
```